# Switch from a UIPickerView to a Keyboard

Tags: ios7, keyboard, uitextfield, uipickerview, uikeyboard

I have a UIPickerView set up with an attached toolbar button that should allow the user to switch from a picker view to a keyboard view.  The pickerView should slide down and a keyboard should slide up in it's place... Theoretically.

The pickerView appears when a user clicks the text field in textFieldDidBeginEditing.

```
    elementPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    [elementPicker setDelegate:self];
    elementPicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    ...
    [_itemElementField setInputView:elementPicker];
```

When the user clicks the "Use Keyboard" button, I have a method to dismiss the picker and call the keyboard.  I can dismiss the pickerview without a problem but CANNOT DISPLAY THE KEYBOARD!!

HELP!

Here is the method called when the user wants the keyboard:

```
-(void)useKeyboardClicked:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"'USE KEYBOARD' BUTTON CLICKED");

    // DISMISS THE PICKER VIEW
    [elementPicker removeFromSuperview];
    [_itemElementField resignFirstResponder];
    _itemElementField.inputAccessoryView = nil;

    // SET ELEMENTPICKER TO THE DEFAULT KEYBOARD
    elementPicker = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    [_itemElementField setInputView:elementPicker];

    // SHOW KEYBOARD
    [_itemElementField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

I'm grasping at straws now and need some help!  I've even gone so far as to try to define a keyboard in the header file with

```
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIKeyboard *elementKeyboard;
```

but that doesn't work AT ALL.

Comment: what is an `_itemElementField`?

Comment: _itemElementField is the name of the text  field the user clicks to call the picker.

Answer (score 0):

Here Is Solution Firstly you have to declare boolean variable checkFlag to keep record of useKeyboardClicked:

then

```
-(void)useKeyboardClick:(id)sender
```

{

```
if (checkFlag) {
    checkFlag=false;
    [txtField setInputView:nil];
    [txtField reloadInputViews];
    [txtField setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceDefault]; //you can set UIKeyboardAppearnce as Dark,light, alert instead of Default
    [txtField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDefault]; // you set decimal keyboard
} else {
    checkFlag=TRUE;

    [txtField setInputView:nil];
    [txtField setInputAccessoryView:numberToolbar];
    [txtField setInputView:pickerView];
}
```

}

One thing i m not total wrong but i can't set back picker view instead keyboard ..... try this i gave you hint ...

Answer (score 0):

for those that might have this issue in the future, the answer ends up being quite simple.
You need to **reload the input view** after resetting it to a keyboard with **reloadInputViews**.

Here's the code:

```
-(void)useKeyboardClicked:(UITextField *)sender {
    NSLog(@"'USE KEYBOARD' BUTTON CLICKED");

    [_itemElementField setInputView:UIKeyboardTypeDefault];
    [_itemElementField becomeFirstResponder];
    [_itemElementField reloadInputViews]; 
}
```